# snowflake current_ip_address to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bigquery-udf

Is there a bigquery equivalent for snowflake's current_ip_address() sql function? If not, can it be implemented via javascript udf? I could not find any relevant information and hence need some inputs.
Here is the snowflake doc about the function:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_ip_address.html

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does not have the IP address of the client that submitted the request, so there is no equivalent (and it can't be implemented using a JavaScript UDF, either).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, BigQuery doesn’t have any function like SQL current_ip_address() with Javascript either. It can just manipulate the IP address with [Net Functions](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions).

You  can get the external or internal IP address from a VM.

You can see these examples.

External IP

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name=my-instance" --format "[box]"
```

Internal IP

```
 gcloud compute instances list --filter="name=my-instance" --format "get(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)" ...
```

You can see this [documentation](https://techoverflow.net/2019/04/01/how-to-find-ip-address-of-google-cloud-vm-instance-on-command-line/).

With Cloud SQL, you can get the IP address from a database:

```
export DB_IP=$(gcloud sql instances describe $DATABASE_ID --project $PROJECT_ID --format 'value(ipAddresses.ipAddress)')
```